# C# Global exception handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

This question has been answered a thousand times but although I've tried everything, I can't seem to get my Global Exception Handler to work.

I'm using a windows form with several async methods. All my async methods are wrapped in `try catch` blocks and handled accordingly. I also have every block of code where I expect an exception wrapped in a `try catch`block.

I'm interested in using a global exception handler to catch exceptions that I'm not expecting so that I can log them and let the user know there has been an exception before safely closing down the program.

In `Main()` I have the following:

```
    [STAThread]
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
    static void Main()
    {
        crashLogInit = InitLogExceptions(); // sets global exception handlers and returns true if successful.
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainWindow = new MainWindow(); // My window
        LoadSaveManager.Init(); // initiates all relavent components for saving and loading data.
        if (isLoaded() && crashLogInit) // Loads data and checks it is successful, also checks global exception handlers are set.
        {
            RunProgram(); //Method which does Application.Run(MainWindow);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, "Error while starting application!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            CloseResources();
        }
    }
```

In the `InitLogExceptions()` I have the following:

```
 private static bool InitLogExceptions()
    {
        try
        {
            crashlogPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), crashlogName);
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; } 
    }
```

In `MainWindow()` I have a button which fires a clicked event which throws an `ArgumentNullException` which is getting caught by the debbugers own exception handler but isnt getting caught by any of mine nor is it getting logged.

Below is the code for my exception handlers:

```
        private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowException(sender, e.Exception, true);
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowException(sender, e.ExceptionObject as Exception, true);
    }

    public static void ApplicationHandler(object sender, Exception e)
    {
        if (!crashLogInit) { InitLogExceptions(); }

        ShowException(sender, e, false);
    }

    public static void ApplicationHandler(object sender, Exception e, bool forceClose)
    {
        if (!crashLogInit) { InitLogExceptions(); }

        ShowException(sender, e, forceClose);
    }



    private static bool WriteToLog(object sender, Exception exception)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

            StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(crashlogPath);

            string date = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd @ HH:mm:ss");

            writer.WriteLine(date + ":");

            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.WriteLine();

            writer.Write($" SENDER: {sender.GetType().ToString()} EXCEPTION MESSAGE: {exception.Message}");
            writer.WriteLine(exception.Source == null ? "" : $"SOURCE: {exception.Source}");
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.WriteLine(exception.StackTrace == null ? exception.InnerException.StackTrace : exception.StackTrace);

            if (exception.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(AppExceptions)))
            {
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.WriteLine($"ORIGINAL MESSAGE: {exception.InnerException.Message} ORIGINAL SOURCE: {exception.InnerException.Source}");
            }

            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.WriteLine();

            writer.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }


    }

    private static void ShowException(object sender, Exception e, bool forceClose)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        if (WriteToLog(sender, e))
        {
            output.AppendLine($"Copied to Crashlog! Location of Crashlog file: {crashlogPath}");
            output.AppendLine();
            output.AppendLine("Send Crashlog to developer!");
        }
        else
        {
            output.AppendLine("Could not copy to Crashlog!");
        }
        output.AppendLine();
        output.AppendLine(forceClose ? "Application will now close!" : "Application will now continue at user's own risk!");


        MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, output.ToString(), e.Message.ToUpper() + "!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        if (forceClose)
        {
            Environment.FailFast(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

Exceptions else where are working and getting logged except this simple thrown exception on a button clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are suppressing possible exceptions inside the method `InitLogExceptions`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, If the InitLogExceptions fails the program won't run. My simulated exception that I'm hoping to catch happens after Application.run so I assume the initlogexception has initiated correctly

Comment: Why do you assume that? Now if `InitLogExceptions` fails you won't even notice. I would at least show a `MessageBox` in this case.

Comment: Yes, After your first comment I changed it to catch( Exception e) log every exception it catches and show a messagebox. Thank you! but the program itself still isn't catching unhandled exceptions

Comment: What happens when an exception occurs? Do you see a message box "Could not copy to Crashlog!" popping up?

Comment: @theodor, when I throw an exception in a try catch and I log it using the showexception() method, it shows the exception and logs it. With unhandled exceptions the program just crashes and visual studios shows me the exception but no messagebox pops up and it’s not logged

Comment: The [`Application_ThreadException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception) handler is supposed to be invoked in case of unhandled exceptions in the UI thread. What's happening in your case? Can you debug your app to figure out if it's invoked or not?

Comment: @theodor I have, and it doesn’t seem to be getting invoked for some reason. But with some exceptions it does and with others it doesn’t